# Creating objects from static properties in python

Tags: python, properties, static, object-construction

I have a Category class which has different names for each categories, the names of the categories can be unknown, good and bad, all categories share the same behavior so i don't want to create sub classes for each type of category, the problem comes when i am trying to
create the different categories in this way:

```
Category.GOOD
```

This statement should return a category object with his name setting to 'good' so i try
the following:

```
class Category(object):                                                                                                            

  def __init__(self, name):                                                                                                      
      self.name = name                                                                                                           

  @property
  def GOOD(self):
      category = Category(name='good')                                                                                           
      return category                                                                                                            

  @property
  def BAD(self): 
      category = Category(name='bad')                                                                                            
      return category
```

Then i created and use the category with the following output:

```
c = Category.GOOD
c.name
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Realizing that this doesn't work i try a java like approach:

```
class Category(object):                                                                                                          

    GOOD = Category(name='good')
    BAD = Category(name='bad')                                                                                                   

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

What i get here is a undefined name "Category" error, so my question is if there is a pythonic way to create a category object like this.

Comment: You cannot do this out-of-the-box with a `property`; you'd have to create your own descriptor instead, or just use a `classmethod` and call `GOOD()`, as given below.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- It's not possible to create a descriptor with this behavior is it?  The problem is that he's accessing the descriptor on the class (which is just an attribute and none of the special descriptor magic comes into play)

Comment: @mgilson: descriptors are invoked for classes as well; `classmethod` is a descriptor too. `function.__get__(None, cls)` gives a 'unbound method' in Python 2 (returns `self` in Python 3), so it is definitely invoked!

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Hmmm... Alright then.  Time to go re-read about descriptors :)

Comment: @mgilson: added that as an answer, it works just fine. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use classmethods:

```
class Category(object):

    @classmethod
    def GOOD(cls):
        category = cls(name='GOOD')
        return category
```

Now you can do `c = Category.GOOD()`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with a property; you either have to use a `classmethod`, or create your own [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) for that:

```
class classproperty(property):
    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        return self.fget(cls)
```

I'm abusing the `property` decorator here; it implements `__set__` and `__del__` as well, but we can just ignore those here for convenience sake.

Then use that instead of `property`:

```
class Category(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classproperty
    def GOOD(cls):
        return cls(name='good')

    @classproperty
    def BAD(cls):
        return cls(name='bad')
```

Now accessing `Category.GOOD` works:

```
>>> Category.GOOD
<__main__.Category object at 0x10f49df50>
>>> Category.GOOD.name
'good'
```

Comment: Upvoted.  In hind-sight, it seems clear that descriptors would need to work on classes (and not just instances) in order to have `classmethod` or `staticmethod` work.  And to think that I've had the wrong idea about these things since I taught myself descriptors a couple months ago...

Answer (score 1):

I'd use module variables for this. Consider you have the module `category.py`:

```
class Category(object):
    # stuff...
```

now you put the two global objects in it:

```
GOOD = Category(name='good')
BAD = Category(name='bad')
```

You can use it like that:

```
from path.to.category import GOOD, BAD
```

I don't say that this is *pythonic* but I think this approach is elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The main point that you could not use class definition inside that class definition itself. So the most straight way to achieve what you are want is to use class/static methods as shown below, or even package constants.

```
class Category(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def GOOD(cls):
        return Category(name='good')

    @classmethod
    def BAD(cls):
        return Category(name='bad')

print Category.GOOD().name
```

or

```
class Category(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def GOOD():
        return Category(name='good')

    @staticmethod
    def BAD():
        return Category(name='bad')

print Category.GOOD().name
```

Comment: You're right -- just copied code from testing another ideas. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, I didn't like writing `GOOD` in all caps.  It seemed too much like yelling ... In any event, this looks correct now :)

Comment: Yes, you're completely right that all-caps function name violates python naming convention. But the question was about feature implementation and not about code style. Hence, the less code changes introduced the more understandable answer is.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine (not changing it is the right thing to do).  I just wanted you to know that I wasn't yelling at you ... I try to be a friendly fellow around here for the most part ...